# The effect of air drag in weightlessness of rocket

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics

Imagine that a rocket is going up at a high speed and after some time its engine shuts off and it separates from the rocket. In such a situation, drag and gravity are both downwards. Does the same direction of drag and gravity cause weightlessness? If yes, why? If not why? And in general, what does this same orientation cause?